# Difference between np.dot() and np.multiply

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am converting my matlab funtion to python. I want to rewrite this simple functions in python

```
function [ H ] = update_H( X , W , H )

     H = H.*((W'*X)./secu_plus(W'*W*H,eps));

end

function [ W ] = update_W( X , W , H )

     W = W.*((X*H')./secu_plus(W*(H*H'),eps));

end
```

Note: `secu_plus` is another function so ignore.

As you may see there are 2 kinds of multiplication `*` and `.*`, Also I have `./`

so what are the equivalent forms in python `[(.* )  (./ ) and (*) ]`

Comment: `.*` is 'element-wise', same as `*` in numpy.  `np.dot` and `@` is matrix multiply.

Answer (score 0):

In *Matlap*, .*operation* means element wise operation, for example if array1 = [ 1,2,3] and array3 [1,2,1], the `.*` will be [1,4,3]
The equivalent of this in *Python numpy*  is `np.multiply`

`np.dot` is the dot product between two vectors, dot product mathematically is the value of the product of the two vectors multiplied by cosine the angle in between, in a two  dimensional coordinates it is equivalent to X1 * X2 + Y1 * Y2
As a general form A.B = sum ai*bi

so just use `np.multiply()` as equivalent to `.*`

Comment: Cool so what about just * should i use same * in python? and lastly ./ will be np.divide in python?

Comment: Yes * will do the same as np.multiply, the difference is that np.multiply can take additional arguments, I don’t think you need this for very simple array multiplication. Yes ./ is np.divide

Comment: @FaroukYahaya did this answer your question?

Comment: yes thanks. how do i mark it as answer. new to all this.

Comment: Just check the mark beside the answer to toggle it from grayed out to filled in

Answer (score 0):

In np.multiply() number of columns for both arrays should be the same:

```
l = np.array([[1,2],[4,5],[7,8]])
a = np.array([[2,3]]
np.multiply(l,a)
output:
array([[ 8],
       [23],
       [38]])
```

where in np.dot() number of columns in first matrix= number of rows in second matrix

```
l = np.array([[1,2],[4,5],[7,8]])
a = np.array([[2,3]]).reshape(2,1)
np.dot(l,a)
output
array([[ 2,  6],
       [ 8, 15],
       [14, 24]])
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/68085301/23173978) is incorrect.

It should be:

```
l = np.array([[1,2],[4,5],[7,8]])
a = np.array([[2,3]])
np.multiply(l,a)

output:
array([[ 2,  6],
       [ 8, 15],
       [14, 24]])
```

`np.multiply` is element-wise multiplication, you multiply the corresponding components, but do not aggregate by summation. So the output should be the same shape as the input `l`.

```
l = np.array([[1,2],[4,5],[7,8]])
a = np.array([[2,3]]).reshape(2,1)
np.dot(l,a)

output:
array([[ 8],
       [23],
       [38]])
```

`np.dot` is dot product, you multiply the corresponding components and add those products together. The output shape is changed because `l` with shape of (3, 2) dot multiply `a` with shape of (2, 1) will give us the output with shape of (3, 1).